# combining values in a loop in sas

Tags: sas, do-loops

In my do loop, I want the first value in the `avail_cashA` column to be equal to the `pool_payment`. And subsequent values in `avail_cashA` equal to `pool_payment + reserve`. I tried updating `avail_cashA` after `output`, but it gave the incorrect values. I know they're wrong because we did this in excel.

I'm not sure how to make this reproducible without providing the whole code, but he below code is not runnable. It specifically contains the relevant portion.

```
do Month = 1 to maturity;
    pool_payment = pmt(coupon, maturity - month + 1, pool_net_bal, 0);

*Certificate A;
    avail_cashA = pool_payment;

 *Money leftover;
    Reserve = avail_cashC - actl_pmtC;

    output;
    avail_cashA = pool_payment + reserve;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update `avail_cashA` before and after `output`, so only the value before `output` will be kept.

```
do Month = 1 to maturity;
    pool_payment = pmt(coupon, maturity - month + 1, pool_net_bal, 0);

    *Certificate A;
    avail_cashA = pool_payment;             *Before;
    *Money leftover;
    Reserve = avail_cashC - actl_pmtC;
    output;

    avail_cashA = pool_payment + reserve;   *After;
end;
```

If you just want derive this variable in one way at the very first time, and in another way at all of the following time, try conditional statement:

```
do Month = 1 to maturity;
    pool_payment = pmt(coupon, maturity - month + 1, pool_net_bal, 0);

    *Certificate A;
    if month=1 then avail_cashA = pool_payment;
    *Money leftover;
    Reserve = avail_cashC - actl_pmtC;
    output;

    avail_cashA = pool_payment + reserve;
end;
```